# Scala pattern matching quick reference

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Where can I find a quick reference card for Scala pattern matching?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [Scala Quick Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/Scala%20Quick%20Reference.pdf#)

Comment: Very nice! I just sent copies to my whole development group.